# How to do an insert on a Table using a fixed parameter and a dynamic one (coming from a SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do an INSERT filling two fields of a table, where one parameter will always have the same value, and the other parameter will be the result of a SELECT

This is what I've done so far:

```
INSERT INTO tabelaAlvo (cdCodigo, cdItem) 
VALUES (8, (SELECT cdItem FROM outraTabela WHERE cdXxx IN (27) AND cdYyy IN (
3,
16,
63,
121,
256,
257,
258,
259,
260,
261,
262,
263,
264)))
```

The first attribute will always take the value = 8, while the second attribute must be taken from the result of a SELECT.

Can you please help me ?.

I've tried to locate a similar question, but I haven't found it.

Comment: This is an English language site - please translate the question or use the site appropriate to your language.

Comment: Please ask your question in English, or ask instead at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Sorry Guys, I thought this site was universal, was unaware of the regional divisions.

Thanks for the tip, Ken!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SELECT to provide multiple records to an insert.

```
INSERT INTO tabelaAlvo (cdCodigo, cdItem) 
       SELECT 8, cdItem 
       FROM outraTabela 
       WHERE cdXxx IN (27) AND 
             cdYyy IN (3, 16, 63, 121, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264)
```